# Integrating Square roots over a seemingly innocent region

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I am currently trying to solve the integral $ \int \int_D \ \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}\ dxdy $ with $D:= ((x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \in [0,1]; \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \leq 1; y \geq 0) $
I have solved it the following way:
$$\int \int_D \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ dxdy = \int_0^1 \int_0^{(1-\sqrt{x})^2} \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \ dydx$$
$$ = \int_0^1 \frac{2((\sqrt{x}-1)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{3} + \sqrt{x^3} -2x + \sqrt{x} dx $$
$$ (((\sqrt{x}-1)^2)^\frac{3}{2}) =(\sqrt{(\sqrt{x}-1)^2})(1-2\sqrt{x}+x)$$
Expanding this part, splitting the integral and using a lot of u-substitutions I computed the integral to be $\frac{4}{15}$ but it took me quite a while.
I was wondering if there was any more efficient method to solving the integral since it seems quite simple to me.

Comment: You could use Green's Theorem.

Comment: Do you know about change of variables in double integrals?

Comment: What would you consider to be a guilty region?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the linearity of the integration operator to simplify the computation:

$$\iint_D \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \, dA = \iint_D \sqrt{x} \, dA + \iint_D \sqrt{y} \, dA = 2 \iint_D \sqrt{x} \, dA, \tag{1}$$ where $dA = dx \, dy$ is the differential area element and $D$ is the region satisfying $0 \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} \le 1$.  Note that we exploited the symmetry of $D$ about the line $y = x$ in the last step of $(1)$.

Next, we compute
$$\begin{align}
\iint_D \sqrt{x} \, dA
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{x} \int_{y=0}^{(1-\sqrt{x})^2} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{x} (1 - \sqrt{x})^2 \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 x^{1/2} - 2x + x^{3/2} \, dx \\
&= \left[\frac{2}{3} x^{3/2} - x^2 + \frac{2}{5}x^{5/2} \right]_{x=0}^1 \\
&= \frac{2}{3} - 1 + \frac{2}{5} \\
&= \frac{1}{15}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the desired integral has value $2/15$.  This approach--exploiting symmetry of both the region of integration and the integrand--avoids the computation of nested square roots for the antiderivative.  As your result is not correct but there is not sufficient work shown to identify the error, I have included [the computation as performed by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5Bx%5D%2BSqrt%5By%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C%281-Sqrt%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%7D%5D) confirming that $2/15$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to apply the change-of-variables formula in double integrals, let $u=\sqrt x$, $v=\sqrt y$ (so $x=u^2$ and $v=y^2$), and then you get
$$\iint_D (\sqrt x+\sqrt y)dx\,dy = \\ \int_0^1\int_0^{1-u} (u+v)\underbrace{4uv}_{\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}}dv\,du = \frac2{15}.$$